# Rewrite the URL in WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have one template having multiple titles,all the details are fetched from the database.

When I click on single title 2nd page is opened with a detailed description with URL link:

```
/category-details/?expertise_category=INSTITUTIONAL
```

but I want only

```
category-details/INSTITUTIONAL as link
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please take a moment to review the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour , 
How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , and more specifically, 
*How to Ask Good Questions* https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 
- you'll get better feedback and helpful answers if you put some thought in to your problem before coming to SO for help, and by including a specific problem with code *that you've tried* showing effort to solve the problem yourself. You can edit your post once you have an idea of the specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use **permalink** functionality of wordpress, there you will find multiple options.
**Choose Postname & save** then you will get what you need.
This document will help you more:
[Wordpress Permalink usage](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Permalinks_Screen)

When you save the permalinks, wordpress by itself rewrites the **.htaccess** file according to the permalink which you have selected.

**Some times the server will not allow wordpress to edit the .htaccess file so you have to set the permissions to your root directory on server.**

Comment: I am new in wordpress.I alredy tried this option but it not working.

Comment: add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpse12965_query_vars' );
function wpse12965_query_vars( $query_vars )
{
    $query_vars[] = 'expertise_category';
   // $query_vars[] = 'var2';
    return $query_vars;
}

Comment: add_action( 'init', 'wpse12065_init' );  
function wpse12065_init() {   
    add_rewrite_rule(  
        'expertise_category/([^/]+)/?',
        'index.php?pagename=category-details&expertise_category=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );   
}

Comment: Can i use this part in my theams's function.php

Comment: You are trying to display all the posts from a category but only thing you need is pretty url right?

Comment: Yes i am trying to create pretty url.

Comment: define( 'WP_DEBUG', true ); Make wp_debug true in wp-config.php file & check the error what you are getting.

Comment: Where to put this - define( 'WP_DEBUG', true ); can i add this currently working template.

Comment: Go to wp-config.php & you will find a predefined constant but it will be false you have to just make it true.

Comment: I tried some code also but it not working.Changes to the htacess file is not affect the url.

Comment: Hope this will help you: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45319/permalink-structure-not-updating-htaccess

Comment: Also go through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26747784/url-rewriting-in-php-using-wordpress?rq=1

Comment: I have gone through your website & its clear that your site is enabled with pretty urls already but only for INSTITUTIONAL BUILDING, RESORTS & other category posts are not using pretty urls that means you have not created category & posts accordingly right?

Comment: Yes.I created custom plugin to add this category to database.And on our-work page simply fetching this.

Comment: Is there any other way to do this

Comment: Yes. In wordpress you dont need to create custom plugin to just create a post. Ex: Copy the content of INSTITUTIONAL & create a page for it & paste it & while opening any specific block of that page open it like your_site_url/institutional#specific_block it will work as expected what is the issue in doing this.

Comment: But there are multiple pages.

Comment: Yes but even for doing that you need to update data in database ryt? And to do that only wordpress is meant for where it directly interact with database without creating hardcoded files for every page.

Comment: Can i chnage htacces file to do this

Answer (score 0):

To get category-details/INSTITUTIONAL, you can create a page called **category-details**, then create another page called **INSTITUTIONAL** and choose the page **category-details** as parent page for **INSTITUTIONAL** page.

If this is a possibility with your current theme, you won't have to change any code but just create multiple pages.

Comment: Could you share the link to the website you are working on?

Comment: Any solution for this